# any Best way to step 1,2,3 .... functions?

Tags: jquery, function, variables, plugins

```
var div = $("div");

one(),two(),three()

function one() {div.css("background", "#f00").hide().fadeIn(1000)};
function two() {div.css("background", "#ff0").hide().fadeIn(1000)};
function three() {div.css("background", "#000").hide().fadeIn(1000)};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aLPLn/

Any plugin like

```
$.stepz(one(),1);
$.stepz(two(),2);
$.stepz(three(),3);
```

???

Comment: Can you please explain your question better - it makes very little sense.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question as well but are you looking for `setInterval` like in: http://jsfiddle.net/aLPLn/1/

Comment: Maybe this one helps you? (Or I maybe dont get it) http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: Ex : one() finished to begin two() .... and more and more

Comment: Yes , thanks for toggle event :D , Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `css` and `hide` are executed immediately, so you don't need to wait for anything there. `fadeIn` on the other hand needs some time to complete, so that is what you wanna wait for. You can pass a callback function that gets called when the animation is complete:

```
var div = $("div");

function one() {div.css("background", "#f00").hide().fadeIn(1000, two)};
function two() {div.css("background", "#ff0").hide().fadeIn(1000, three)};
function three() {div.css("background", "#000").hide().fadeIn(1000)};

one();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ckC9d/

Answer (score 1):

All jQuery animation method supply something called a "callback"-function that is executed when the animation is finished. It is specified right after the duration. You can use this to chain animations like:

```
function one() {div.css("background", "#f00").hide().fadeIn(1000, two)};
function two() {div.css("background", "#ff0").hide().fadeIn(1000, three)};
function three() {div.css("background", "#000").hide().fadeIn(1000, one)};

one(); //this will start a never-ending loop
```

See [this doc](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) for example.